# .txt-File transfer over Network (client/server) - .txt on server contains wrong content

Tags: c#, client-server, file-transfer

I'm working on a client-server program. The client sends the server a .txt file and the server receive this .txt file and saves it.

My problem:
If i send a .txt file which contains the following content: "Hello world" (without "")
then the server recevies/saves a .txt file which contains the following content "ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ" (without "").

The filesize of both files are exact the same.

Here my code:

Client:
Program.cs

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Threading.Tasks;

            namespace FTP_3___Client {
                public class Program {
                    static void Main(string[] args) {
                        new Client();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Client:
Client.cs:

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.ComponentModel;
            using System.Data;
            using System.Drawing;
            using System.IO;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Net;
            using System.Net.Sockets;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Threading.Tasks;
            using FTP_3___Client;

            namespace FTP_3___Client {
                public class Client {

                    public string name { get; set; }
                    public TcpClient clientConnection { get; set; }
                    public NetworkStream nws { get; set; }
                    public StreamReader sr { get; set; }
                    public StreamWriter sw { get; set; }

                    public int sizeOfConnectedClients { get; set; }
                    public string clientnamelistString { get; set; }

                    public Client() {
                        connectToServer();
                        sendFile("zzz.txt");
                    }

                    public void connectToServer() {
                        Console.WriteLine("connect to server...");
                        clientConnection = new TcpClient();
                        IPAddress ipadress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                        clientConnection.Connect(ipadress, 5555);
                        Console.WriteLine("connected to server!");

                        nws = clientConnection.GetStream();
                        sr = new StreamReader(nws);
                        sw = new StreamWriter(nws);
                    }

                    private void sendFile(string filename) {

                        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filename);

                        FileInfo fo = new FileInfo(filename);
                        long filesize = fo.Length;
                        Console.WriteLine("Filesize: " + filesize);

                        sw.WriteLine("/sendFile");
                        sw.Flush();

                        // Send filename to server
                        sw.WriteLine("Filename: " + filename);
                        sw.Flush();

                        // Send filesize to server
                        sw.WriteLine("Filesize: " + filesize);
                        sw.Flush();

                        byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
                        sw.WriteLine(fileBytes.Length);
                        sw.Flush();
                        for (int i = 0; i < fileBytes.Length; i++) {
                            nws.WriteByte(fileBytes[i]);
                        }

                        sr.Close();
                        sw.Close();
                        nws.Close();

                        Console.WriteLine("File sends!");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }

                }
            }
```

---

Server: Program.cs

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Threading.Tasks;

            namespace FTP_3___Server {
                class Program {
                    static void Main(string[] args) {
                        new Server();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Server: Server.cs

```
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using System.Linq;
            using System.Text;
            using System.Threading.Tasks;
            using System.Threading;
            using System.Net;
            using System.Net.Sockets;
            using System.IO;

            namespace FTP_3___Server {
                public class Server {

                    private IPAddress ipadress;
                    private TcpListener serverconnection;
                    private TcpClient clientconnection;
                    public NetworkStream nws { get; set; }
                    public StreamReader sr { get; set; }
                    public StreamWriter sw { get; set; }

                    public Server() {
                        startServer();
                        waitForClient();
                    }

                    public void startServer() {
                        ipadress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
                        serverconnection = new TcpListener(ipadress, 5555);
                        serverconnection.Start();
                    }

                    public void waitForClient() {
                        Console.WriteLine("Server startet. Waiting for incoming client connections...");
                        clientconnection = serverconnection.AcceptTcpClient();
                        nws = clientconnection.GetStream();
                        sr = new StreamReader(nws);
                        sw = new StreamWriter(nws);
                        Console.WriteLine("Client connected with Server!");

                        receiveMessage();
                    }

                    public void receiveMessage() {

                        string receivedMessage = sr.ReadLine();

                        switch (receivedMessage) {
                            case "/sendFile": {
                                    receiveFile();
                                    break;
                                }
                            default: {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Received undefined message: " + receivedMessage);
                                    break;
                                }
                        }

                    }

                    public void receiveFile() {
                        // Recieve filename
                        string filename = sr.ReadLine().Remove(0, 10);

                        // Recieve filesize
                        long filesize = Convert.ToInt64(sr.ReadLine().Remove(0, 10));

                        Console.WriteLine("Filename: " + filename);
                        Console.WriteLine("Filesize: " + filesize);

                        long count = filesize;
                        int arrayLength = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine());
                        byte[] filebytes = new byte[arrayLength];

                        for (int i = 0; i < filebytes.Length; i++) {
                            filebytes[i] = (byte)nws.ReadByte();
                        }

                        try {
                            File.WriteAllBytes(filename, filebytes);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                        }

                        sr.Close();
                        sw.Close();
                        nws.Close();

                        Console.WriteLine("File was written on HDD. Finish!");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Don't blindly cast the return value of `nws.ReadByte()` to `byte`, check whether it returns -1 as that indicates the end of the stream.

Comment: I changed it and now the .txt file the server received contains only 11 spaces....

Comment: That means that either the file contents were never received on the server end *or* you have already read past it. Perhaps `StreamReader` has read those bytes and buffered them? I don't think you're supposed to read from `StreamReader` *and* directly from the underlying stream.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was my problem! I just now read/write the filebytes not with the Networkstream but with the Streamreader/Streamwriter.

Answer (score 0):

C.Evenhuis gave the answer in the comments.